# Why can't I call my function?

Tags: rust

```
struct Floor{
    requestHandler: Option<RequestHandler>
}

struct RequestHandler{
    uri: StrBuf,
    handler: fn() -> StrBuf
}

impl Floor {

    fn do_something(&self){
        //(&self.requestHandler.unwrap().handler)();
        //expected function but found `&fn() -> std::strbuf::StrBuf`

        //(*(&self.requestHandler.unwrap().handler))();
        //cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer

        //(self.requestHandler.unwrap().handler)();
        //cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
    }
}

fn main() {

    let foo = Floor {
        requestHandler: None
    };

    foo.do_something();
}
```

In `do_something` I try to get to my `fn` which is stored on the `handler` property of my `RequestHandler` struct.

Whatever I try, I just seem to be unable to call it (see the compiler messages beneath my failed attempts in the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the signature of [`Option.unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/option/type.Option.html#method.unwrap):

```
impl Option<T> {
    fn unwrap(self) -> T { ... }
}
```

That is, it is taking the `Option` by value. `RequestHandler` has to move when used by value, since `StrBuf` moves (specifically `StrBuf` isn't [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/kinds/trait.Copy.html) which forces `RequestHandler` to also not be `Copy`).

The correct way to handle this is to call [`Option.as_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/option/type.Option.html#method.as_ref):

```
impl Option<T> {
    fn unwrap<'r>(&'r self) -> Option<&'r T> { ... }
}
```

That is, it takes a reference to an `Option` and gives you an `Option` containing a reference to what the original `Option` contained, this means that `.unwrap` will then give you that reference, pointing to the `RequestHandler` inside `self`, to handle as you wish.

```
(self.requesthandler.as_ref().unwrap().handler)()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you explain what is preventing it to move `RequestHandler`? Why do we need the reference? Can't it just move it if it has to? This may sound very dumb but I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of all this stack, heap, pointer, references stuff.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but the tutorial somewhat covers these ideas ([sections 9 to 11](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/tutorial.html#ownership)) and Nicholas Matsakis's [recent "Guaranteeing memory safety in Rust" talk](https://air.mozilla.org/guaranteeing-memory-safety-in-rust/) touches on borrowing and ownership.

Comment: Yep, I've read this multiple times and also watched that video. I understand it in theory but I can't apply it to all of my own examples yet. These days I wish I had a better understanding of C/C++. Would be really helpful when learning Rust.

Comment: Ok, here is what I think you mean, maybe you could tell me if that's correct: `RequestHandler` would have to *move* which essentially mean that `Floor.requestHandler` would become `null` which is not allowed because `Floow` *owns* the `requestHandler` property. Therefore we need to get a reference to not having to move `RequestHandler`. Is that correct?

Comment: Update: `get_ref` doesn't seem to exist anymore for `Option<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, removed the mention.